Publishing / Correcting map -> base_link transform based off detected landmark
I am developing a mobile robot using slam_toolbox and the nav2 stack. As a part of nav2, I have created a dock for the robot, using Apriltags to localize the robot wrt the dock. Since I know the exact location of the dock wrt the map frame, is there any way for me to use these transforms to localize the robot, correcting the slam_toolbox localization.
Currently my tf is the standard map -> odom -> base_link, with the ARTag pose being published as base_link -> camera -> dockTag. Is it possible to use some sort of dockTag -> map transform? Any help would be appreciated.

One way to do this is to publish the Apriltags transformation to /initialpose topic. The localization will recalculate the position after feeding it this information.
Another way is to use the Kalman filter by combining the odometry and the Apriltags position.
